# PHP - Store multiple select option into array and us the ID as array key

Tags: php, arrays

I have selectbox option list with multiple selection.

```
<select multiple="MULTIPLE" size="20" name="facilities[]">
   <option id="idOne" value="Value One">Value One</option>
   <option id="idTwo" value="Value Two">Value Two</option>
   <option id="idThree" value="Value Three">Value Three</option>
</select>
```

I have done already the php code that can store the value into an Array on my database, but.. what I want now, is that possible to use the ID from the option as a key of the array, so when you storing the array will look like sample below

```
array('idOne'=>'Value One', 'idTwo'=>Value Two, 'idThree'=>'Value Three')
```

Instead of `array([0]=>'Value One', [1]=>Value Two, [2]=>'Value Three')` (that what I get now).

Any kind help will much appreciate :)

Sorry my English bad.

Comment: Technically not possible. HTML `id` attributes are NOT sent with the form. You'd have to embed the ids into your value somehow, e.g. `idOne-Value One` and then split that value into key/value pairs in PHP. That or have a value->id map in your server-side code.

Comment: Hi @MarcB that make sense, add the id into value and split it into array to given a key :), thanks...

Comment: Hi @MarcB that's work, thanks here the code I use for `$test = array();
foreach($_POST['facilities'] as $key=>$value) {
   $Gkey = explode(",",$value);
   $test[$Gkey[0]] = $Gkey[1];
}
 
print_r($test); // array('idOne'=>'Value One', 'idTwo'=>Value Two, 'idThree'=>'Value Three')`

Comment: you might be better off just having the IDs as your values anyways. Especially if those options are being created from a DB or something. All you need to send back to the server is the ID of the value that was selected. You can always look up the value again. And round-tripping values through the client, e.g. `200" flatscreen tv - $0.00` could be sent back very easily.

Comment: Yes I agree with your answer above, that's a very easy way, I just could not realize it ...he...he...

Answer (score 0):

By definition, only the `value` of your `option` tags will be passed in your POST. There's a couple of options here

First, you would need to know the values on the other end and marry them up. This is more work potentially but you would always have a list of the values selected.

```
  $vals = array('idOne'=>'Value One', 'idTwo'=>'Value Two', 'idThree'=>'Value Three');
  foreach($vals as $key => $row) {
       if(array_search($row, $_POST['facilities']) === false) unset($vals[$key]);
  }
```

Second would be to use JavaScript and build a list of the `text` values that are selected and POST that (either via hidden field or using AJAX). This is riskier since the data would be in the client's hands but still doable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, I got the solution already :)